# error, Signature not verified, wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

The Plugin is a movie importer
site had to be all redone as server crashed & i forgot backup.

the plugin : http://scriptburn.com/downloads/wordpress-movie-plugin/

when i go to dashboard to import its saying: error, Signature not verified

It worked perfect on old server

What could be wrong

I have the plugin with proper license keys.

Anyone understand it?

Comment: every once in a while it works